# sendRawTransaction not appearing / being submitted to the network

Tags: web3js, transactions, myetherwallet, raw-transaction

I'm new to Javascript, so bear with me. I've successfully gotten web3.js working in a HTML file, with getBalances working as it should. (I don't want to use Node.js for now)

However now I'm stuck at sending a raw transaction. The console tells me that a transaction hash is created, but when I search on Etherscan the transaction does not appear. Also no ETH is transferred between the 'from' and the 'to' address.

My code in the HTML file:

```
      const gasLimitInHex = web3.toHex(30000)

      const valueInWei = web3.toWei('0.05', 'ether')
      const valueWeiInHex = web3.toHex(valueInWei)

      const rawTx = {
        gasLimit: gasLimitInHex,
        to: receiveEthAddress,
        value: valueWeiInHex
      }

      const tx = new EthJS.Tx(rawTx)
      tx.sign(privateKey)

      var serializedTx = tx.serialize()

      console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'))

      web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(hash)
        } else {
          console.log(err)
        }
      })
```

The serialized tx: `f866808082753094e1677d96bb82668bb188ec71498db5c0c0c4830e87b1a2bc2ec50000801ba0754d70a1dcbca6a7486fafeed8e63c8738b401af562697c2d97c990c4ac3d543a02a0664aeaa900c4d1d8ad94c3c69b76bcaa5f5c3e8307c4d63c86d60b70f4d7b`

The transaction hash that web3.js returns: `0x9b89dad10e235d9bbd4b48f6a9768b557861281645b6d0702115e4a7141b0f41`

FYI I'm using the myetherwallet API (https://api.myetherapi.com/eth)

Comment: It appear from your code that nonce is missing. You can obtain it by doing `var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(0xaddress);`

Comment: Thanks. You're correct, the nonce was missing. I also realised that gasPrice is also needed for the rawTransaction to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ismael for pointing me in the right direction.

Both the nonce and gasPrice were missing.

For nonce:

```
var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(0xaddress);
```

For gasPrice:

```
var gasPriceInWei = web3.toWei('10', 'gwei');
```

Both nonce and gasPrice need to be converted to hex.